# How to merge multiple word file into one word file according to the content

Tags: python, vba, ms-word

For example, there are 3 word files (Name: word_1, word_2, word_3), and I would like to merge all the content into word_1.

**Before merge:**

```
Content in word_1:
1.1.1 Hello World
      testing text 111

1.1.2 Hello America
      testing text 222

1.1.3 Hello USA


1.1.4 Hello Korea


1.1.5 Hello Japan

Content in word_2:
1.1.3 Hello USA
      testing text 333

1.1.4 Hello Korea
      testing text 444

Content in word_3:
1.1.5 Hello Japan
      testing text 888

1.1.6 Hello Germany
      testing text 999
```

**After merge:**

```
1.1.1 Hello World
      testing text 111

1.1.2 Hello America
      testing text 222

1.1.3 Hello USA
      testing text 333

1.1.4 Hello Korea
      testing text 444

1.1.5 Hello Japan
      testing text 888
```

Basically it is merge by the ID next to the topic (i.e. 1.X.X, X.X.X), I assume there is no duplicate ID, every ID is unique. Current I find some resources as the code below and I can only merge the word file to another word file. Thank you so much for you help. It is also ok if it can realize in python.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MergeFilesInAFolderlntoOneDoc()
Dim dlgFile As FileDialog
Dim wdApp As Object, oRng As Object
Dim objDoc As Object, objNewDoc As Object
Dim StrFolder As String, strFile As String
    Set dlgFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With dlgFile
        If .Show = -1 Then
            StrFolder = dlgFile.SelectedItems.Item(1) & Chr(92)
        Else
            MsgBox ("No folder is selected!")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err Then
        Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    strFile = Dir(StrFolder & "*.docx", vbNormal)
    With wdApp
        .Visible = True
        Set objNewDoc = .Documents.Add
        While strFile <> ""
            Set objDoc = .Documents.Open(FileName:=StrFolder & strFile)
            With objNewDoc
                Set oRng = .Range
                If Len(oRng) > 1 Then
                    oRng.Collapse 0
                    oRng.InsertBreak 7
                End If
                oRng.Collapse 0
                oRng.FormattedText = objDoc.Range.FormattedText
                objDoc.Close 0
            End With
            DoEvents
            strFile = Dir()
        Wend
        objNewDoc.Activate
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `regex` and some string manipulation

```
a = """Content in word_1:
1.1.1 Hello World
      testing text 111

1.1.2 Hello America
      testing text 222

1.1.3 Hello USA


1.1.4 Hello Korea


1.1.5 Hello Japan"""

b = """Content in word_2:
1.1.3 Hello USA
      testing text 333

1.1.4 Hello Korea
      testing text 444"""

c = """Content in word_3:
1.1.5 Hello Japan
      testing text 888

1.1.6 Hello Germany
      testing text 999"""

import re
def create_dict(text):
    d = {}
    res = re.finditer(r"[1-9]{1}\.[1-9]{1}\.[1-9]{1}", text)
    l = list(res)
    for x, y  in zip(l, l[1:]):
        d[x.group()] = text[x.span()[1]: y.span()[0]]
    d[l[-1].group()] = text[l[-1].span()[1]: ]
    return d


def merge_text(parent, *texts):
    temp_d = {parent.splitlines()[0]: create_dict(parent)}
    for d in texts:
        temp_d[parent.splitlines()[0]].update(create_dict(d))
    return "\n".join([parent.splitlines()[0], *temp_d[parent.splitlines()[0]].values()])
merge_text(a, b, c)
```